# Image movement/gravity issues in processing 2.2.1

Tags: image, image-processing, processing

I'm trying to apply gravity to an image that I've loaded into my processing data files. All the images work fine, and everything is good. However, the gravity condition that I set up for an object that was previously just a shape does not work with the image I put in its place.

Here's the source code, sorry if it's really sloppy...I'm a newb.

Basically I have a stick image, a background image, and a balloon. I want the balloon to release when I click the mouse, and fly upwards. It was working fine when I was just using simple objects, but as soon as I used stored images I ran into errors. What have I done wrong? How badly have I bungled this code? I'm really going crazy trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

By the way, I'm using processing 2.2.1

```
float line;
float xpos;
float ypos;
float speed = 1;
float gravity = 1;
int bodyHeight = 160;

float easing = 0.02;
PImage b;
PImage lol;
PImage balloon;

void setup(){
    size(500,500);

    b=loadImage("1406075208097 copy.jpg");
    lol=loadImage("Dark-Wood-Background.jpg");
    //Here's where I have trouble
    balloon=loadImage("1194986736244974413balloon-red-aj.svg.thumb.png");
    xpos = (mouseX);
    ypos = (mouseY);

    }


void draw(){

    //DRAW BACKGROUND
    background(b);


    stroke(0);
    //DRAW THE TETHER
    line(width/2,height/2,mouseX,mouseY);
    //THE BALLOON
    noStroke();
    fill(245,91,97);
    image(balloon,mouseX-10,mouseY-30);
    //THE STICK
    noStroke();
    fill(144,113,73);
    image(lol,228,250);

    //This next section sets up the conditions for the balloon on the stick.
    if(mousePressed){
    //DRAW BACKGROUND
    background(b);


    stroke(0);
    //DRAW THE TETHER
    line(width/2,height/2,mouseX,mouseY);
    //THE STICK
    image(lol,228,250);
    //THIS NEXT SECTION IS FOR THE UPWARD MOVING BALLOON
    image(balloon,mouseX-10,mouseY-30);

    ypos = speed-.9999999;

    speed = speed - gravity;
    // If square reaches the bottom
    // Reverse speed
    if (ypos > height){

    speed = speed * -99.99999999999999999999999999999;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please help me free my balloon.

Comment: What errors are you getting? What do you mean by "here's where I have trouble"?

Comment: Well, before I established a float for ypos,and xpos I was just having my if mouse pressed statement try to reference the balloon image I have in there. Whenever I ran that code, it said that it could not convert a Pimage to float. This was my first problem. I want the image of the balloon to work with the gravity conditions I set up in the code. When it was just drawn shape, the shape of the balloon floated upwards quite nicely and left the screen via the top. I want the same thing from the image file, but I don't quite know how to get it to do so.

Comment: I'm making a little flash game in which you free the balloon by clicking it, allowing it to soar upwards.

Comment: Once I put the xpos and ypos in there, I stopped getting the conversion error, but the balloon doesn't follow the if statement anymore. It doesn't change states as I wanted it to. Pretty new to processing, but devoting 8 hours a day to it. So trying to figure this out is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this line:

```
 image(balloon,mouseX-10,mouseY-30);
```

You're always drawing the balloon image at the mouse position. You're never using the xpos or ypos variables to draw the balloon image.

Try actually using the xpos and ypos to position the balloon when you draw it.

Comment: Amazing, it works. Now one last question for now. When I click the balloon it only does the floating animation for one click of the mouse. Is there a way in processing of repeating the whole animation?

Comment: Look at your if(mousePressed) logic. That will only execute while the mouse is currently pressed. You have to examine your logic and really think about what you want to happen, and when you want it to happen.

Comment: Thanks, I cleaned it all up a bit. I added a void mouseClicked function so that I can have things stay in a state after the mouse if clicked. Now I just need to clean up more code. Thank you very much.

Comment: Also, I added the int state1 and int state2, so essentially I could have two phases of being for the balloon: floating and stuck on mouse position.